# Не очищается память после создания архива DotNetZip

Tags: c#, visual-studio, многопоточность, dotnetzip

В мое программе используется создание архива методом DotNetZip. Все в принципе работает, но меня смущает что после создания архива, моя программа отъедает 500 МБ оперативно памяти. Можно ли как-то почистить буфер DotNetZip или завершить поток в котором он выполнялся.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(t =>
                {
                    using (Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zip = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile())
                    {

                        try
                        {
                            zip.AddDirectory(@logPath);
                            zip.Save(FilePath);
                            ChekFile(param);

                        }
                        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
                        {
                            Program.log.Error("Directory not found! " + ex.ToString());

                        }
                        catch(Exception ex)
                        {
                            Program.log.Error("Error ZIP" + ex.ToString());

                        }
                   }
                })
                { IsBackground = true };
                thread.Start();
```

Comment: ну вызовите метод Dispose после создания или в случае возникновения ошибки

Comment: @OlegLylok Оператор using гарантирует вызов метода Dispose

Comment: @AK не спорю, что практически тоже самое. тогда он может попытаться вызвать GC, чтоб тот забрал мусор (пардон) :)

Comment: Уборщик мусора сам решает, когда ему мусор убирать, или вы можете вызвать `GC.Collect();` наприямую. То, что память висит - ни о чем не говорит, если вы подозреваете утечку памяти, то вам надо её искать спец средствами (например dotMemory), но если утечки нет - то делать ничего не надо - когда сборщику надо будет, он сам память очистит.

Comment: А поток у вас сам умрет, как только сделает то, что требуется. Но, мне кажется, вам тут и поток создавать не надо, почему бы просто не отправить таск в пул потоков? `Task.Run(()=>{...});` ?

Comment: Спасибо все за ответы. Да действительно, через какое то время память очищается.